# Why does this Exception Occur? networking (Connection Refused)

Tags: java

*In this program i have tried to make my pc both server and client. *The  error that i get is "Connection Refused"

This is my program:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    class chatboxClient {
    JFrame fr;
    JPanel p;
    JButton send;
    JTextArea ta;
    JRadioButton rb;

     chatboxClient() {
     new chatboxServer();
     fr=new JFrame("ChatBox_CLIENT");
     p=new JPanel();
     send=new JButton("send");
     ta=new JTextArea();
     ta.setRows(20);
     ta.setColumns(20);
     rb=new JRadioButton("Connect");               // action listener for connect
     rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       connectActionPerformed(ae); 
      }
    });
    fr.add(p);
    p.add(ta);
    p.add(rb);
    p.add(send);
    fr.setSize(500,500);
    fr.setResizable(false);
    fr.setVisible(true);
   }

    public void connectActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     try {
       InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
       Socket s=new Socket(address,3000); // create connection with port number 3000 of server 
        if(s.isConnected()==true) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Connection successfully Established");
        } else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Error Creating Connection");
          }
     } catch(Exception exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),exc); // line A
       }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
     new chatboxClient();
    }
   }
```

**SERVER SIDE:**

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    class chatboxServer {
    JFrame fr;
    JPanel p;
    JTextArea ta;
    JButton send;

    chatboxServer() {
    fr=new JFrame("ChatBox_SERVER");
    p=new JPanel();
    ta=new JTextArea();
    ta.setRows(20);
    ta.setColumns(20);
    send=new JButton("send");
    fr.add(p);
    p.add(ta);
    p.add(send);
    fr.setVisible(true);
    fr.setSize(500,500);
    fr.setResizable(false);
   }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
     new chatboxServer();
    }
   }
```

**Here I get Exception (When i press connect) corresponding to the only try statement that i have.** *(Labeled A)*
**What is the reason that i am getting exception?** *Note: chatboxServer() is a class defined in the same directory.*

Through this program i want that message typed in one window goes to another window.I have made my pc both server and client.

Comment: What error do you get? Please post error log.

Comment: Which exception are you getting? Does it have the message "Connection refused" ?  There are lots of possible exceptions. The fastest way to know what they mean is to *read* them and try to search for the error mesage.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey yes i get connection refused

Comment: Temporary -1 for not including enough information.

Comment: @Suhail - well, what then, is your question? "Connection refused" usually means that nobody is listening on the port you are connecting to.

Comment: @ Ingo I have written that i dont have the idea that why i am getting this error.'Now' you should get the question

Comment: @ Lord Torgamus i have added now

Comment: is the server part of your program opening up a ServerSocket on port 3000?

Comment: Please post the code of chatboxServer.

Comment: @Suhail, I told you why you get this error: Because nothing is listening on port 3000, or your program is not allowed to connect to port 3000 due to firewall rules (though, in that case I would rather expect a "Connection timeout")

Comment: Wait let me post the code of server side...

Comment: @ Ingo then can you suggest a way out

Comment: @ Jon Bright yes i have posted now

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy you can have a look now

Answer (score 0):

If you don't believe us when we say that Connection Refused means there is no server listening on that port, you can just google for it. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Connection+Refused 3,620,000 hits

Comment: Then how should i make server listen

Answer (score 0):

There is no server in your code. The only code I can see is a GUI for the server. Not actual server.